# Find Gsheet ID with BigQuery Data Connector

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to manage BigQuery costs and the biggest offenders of cost are coming from connected Gsheets. I have the source query to understand the cost using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT`, but I am unable to find the sheet that has the query in it.
Has anyone found a solution to trace back a Query job from a job_id that is prefixed with `sheets_dataconnector_` to the sheet it is connected to?

Comment: How is this related to programming?